# Is there a way you can Hack Wireless Capabillities into a Gamecube?

Tags: wireless-networking

Alright, I am getting a GameCube for really cheap from a friend, but I want it to do more than just play games, I want to run it off of Linux.  I did some research, finding that some distros did exist.  Further than that, I want to be able to surf the internet on Wi-Fi.  Is there anyway that I can easily do this?

NB: I am cable of some electrical modifications, but am still limited.

EDIT: on a semi-related note, can you get a Wi-Fi receiver that plugs into an Ethernet port?

Comment: Consider getting a Wii instead, it runs GameCube and has Wi-Fi... ;)

Comment: I know, I know.  I have one, but my parents took it away :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easily?  Probably not.  A quick Google doesn't turn up anyone having hacked a WiFi adapter into (or onto) a GameCube.

It might be theoretically possible, since an Ethernet adapter was available, but you'll be more or less on your own making it work.  Your biggest challenge will be making it work via the GC's serial port so that it's powered and communicates with the GC itself.

I'd only consider the endeavor worthwhile if you don't place any value on your time or the materials required to pull this off.  It's going to be a lot cheaper and easier to just use a Wii with the WiFi built in or hunt down the Broadband Adapter (Ethernet), which doesn't seem to be outrageously expensive.  (It's cheaper than the Component cables!)

Comment: Yeah yeah yeah, I know.  Everybody I have even vaguely mentioned this to has said "Just get a Wii", and I have one, but my parents have taken it away and I haven't used it a LONG time, so that wont happen.  +1 anyways for a good answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: If you get the broadband adapter, you could probably use a linksys wrt54g or some other similar router in "Client Bridge" mode (with DD-WRT anyway), which you could then connect the gamecube to.

Comment: @Rob: That's a good idea.  Wireless bridges would also work, but might be both more expensive and less flexible.

Comment: Holy crap, I have a wrt54g sitting in my basement, in a box, collecting dust!  So I would just load the DD-WRT firmware to the router, right?

Comment: Assuming it's a HW revision that an alternate firmware can be loaded onto... yeah. It's just a matter of flashing the firmware and correctly configuring it.

Comment: Yikes!  I am in eighth grade!  That went straight over my head, but that's all right...  I guess.